# PDF error - use another PDF viewer or use libreoffice instead?

Tags: pdf

I am using PDF forms made using latex to register/configure the changes to my company's products for 1 year now. I decided it is better from using Libreoffice or MS word since the pdf file size is smaller, there is compatibility with the file, and it does not generate temporary files when being edited like ms word or libreoffice.

[image: latex pdf]

But today I run into a problem I have not seen before happening with MS word/libreoffice.

My hard drive got unplug while I was working on the pdf and when I re-opened the pdf, Adobe acrobat said "there was an error opening this document. the file is damaged and could not be repaired." when I tried to open the pdf.

[image: pdf error]

Now, when this happened with ms word/libreoffice It could repair/recover the file always. Or at least let me open the file. But in this case I could not open the file via Adobe. I managed to open the pdf using a web browser, and I saw that just some changes I made to the pdf were not registered but it was fine overall. But when I tried to download that file from the browser and save it, the Adobe again could not open the file, it showed me the same error.

Now I wonder, is that just a disadvantage of using PDF files? that they are hard(er) to recover in case of an error, or do I use a bad PDF viewer? I mean my browser could open the pdf just fine, but adobe PDF viewer, which only job is to open PDFs, did not even try to open the pdf, just a error with no more details.

Comment: I'd avoid the issue entirely by hardening your backup structure.

Comment: @Tetsujin I know right? hard drives should not get un-plugged randomly. Its a USB hard drive so its sensitive to touch. If I move the USB A a little bit that plugs on the laptop it just loses synchronization.

Comment: You can run the PDF file through `qpdf` or `cpdf` to see if it can be repaired. If not, try putting it though GhostScript, which is the best at dealing with malformed files, but at the cost of reprocessing the whole file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of PDF is that you can open the document in any digital platform in any size or print it to a book, and the page layout will never change.

PDF as a file format is an [Adobe creation in the first place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF). It's standardized, until 2007 when Adobe released specification 1.7 to standard organizations. Now it's an ISO standard ([ISO 32000](https://www.pdfa.org/resource/iso-32000-pdf/)) and Adobe is just one member in the technical committee. However Adobe Acrobat and Adobe Reader are strict on the correctness of the format, third party applications or browsers are much more lax.

What this basically means is that if Adobe Reader says your PDF is damaged or corrupt, the doesn't adhere to the standard. You might be able to fix it with a PDF editor, but the simplest way is just to delete the file and export it again from the original application.